# How to make volume control in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ipad

i am using MPMoviePlayerController to play the movie,using duration value to control video duration in the player,but i did know how control volume in use of slider
my volume slider code is here,and iam using custom image to slider in my program,

```
{
    UISlider *volumeslider=[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(405, 9, 50, 3)];
        UIImage *volumesliderImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"video_bar_bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 9 topCapHeight: 0];
        [volumeslider setMinimumTrackImage: volumesliderImage  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [volumeslider setMaximumTrackImage: volumesliderImage  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [volumeslider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sound_bar_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [tempview addSubview:volumeslider];
}
```

Comment: moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault has volume control

Answer (score 1):

i am solved my problem use this code

```
-(void)sliderAction
{
 [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:sliderValue];
//it only work in device not work in simulator

}
```

Comment: how to get current volume value. i used   `NSLog(@"%f",[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer].volume);`, but it displays -1022623021699233405194582622208.000000

Comment: @murugha23 // The current volume of playing music, in the range of 0.0 to 1.0.
// This property is deprecated -- use MPVolumeView for volume control instead.
@property(nonatomic) float volume NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0, 7_0);

Answer (score 0):

i think refer this answer it may be help to you to make UISlider of volume to increase or decrease level [iphone - MPMoviePlayerController - How can I decrease volume of the video programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870465/iphone-mpmovieplayercontroller-how-can-i-decrease-volume-of-the-video-progra) and also try to implement this method

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:<Give your frame>];
[volumeSlider addSubview:volumeView];
[volumeView sizeToFit];
```

it's work in my app

Comment: iam use this code the slider value only change,volume not increase and  decrese